# How to achieve this shader parallax effect on any shaped object?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

This current example is made from a composited scene. I want to try to replicate this in shader nodes, what's a shader vector mapping system to get this effect?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this setup:

[image]

It calculates where the camera view vector hits the parallax plane (defined with the object's center and $\vec{n}=(0,0,1)$) and uses that to derive the texture coordinates.

Note: you may want to change the usage of the part starting from `Looking to Plane?` for your needs. In the given setup it just points back to $(0,0)$ texture coordinates to show that the plane is not hit.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Cleanly done :)