# Parallax shader in eevee

Tags: shader-nodes

How can i achieve the same effect but with the plane oriented such a way it faces x axis.

[How to achieve this shader parallax effect on any shaped object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299993/how-to-achieve-this-shader-parallax-effect-on-any-shaped-object/312437#312437)

From the above post.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: So is it okay if I use the link of another post on blender stack exchange, or is there any built-in way to mention another question?

Comment: Links to posts are ok, but you should illustrate your post in such way that one doesn't have to visit external links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the normal input to be X axis:

[image]

Change the output to be along Y and Z and recombine Y Z to be X Y:

[image]

Note: the circle surface should face Y axis, with no rotation.

Comment: And if i want to make it facing y axis? Trust me I am also trying to change values by myself but it is not working :(

Comment: What is "it" in "make it facing y axis"? The plane or the circle?

Comment: the plane i mean

Comment: so to be // to the disk surface?

Comment: yes i want it to be in a depth from the surface

Comment: Using incoming output from geometry.

Comment: Thanks i got it working :))