# Parallax shader in EEVEE Part 2

Tags: shader-nodes

Reference post: - [How to achieve this shader parallax effect on any shaped object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299993/how-to-achieve-this-shader-parallax-effect-on-any-shaped-object/312437#312437)

So, I want to make something similar, but I want the plane to follow object rotations and positions. But without using a UV map or tangents because that will not work with curved surfaces, I want the plane to stay a plane and not distort.

Thank you :)